# Encoding of video using built in Windows functionality (Media Foundation)?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I've been investigating various method of exporting video from my FMX application, in particular mp4 using the h.264 codec. One method is to use FFmpeg with the FFVCL components. The down side of this is that including FFmpeg dlls with my application increases the download size. The other problem is the licensing issue of using the libx264 encoder. There is a free to use libopenh264 encoder but isn't as good as it only supports the Baseline profile.

However, Windows has video encoding built in which includes the full h.264 with High profile (mfh264enc.dll). This seems like the ideal solution for high quality video export while minimising the size of my application and avoiding licensing problems. The following page gives information on the video encoding interface in Windows.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/overview-of-encoding-in-media-foundation

My question is how can I call this from Delphi to export video from a sequence of images stored in TBitmap? My application is FMX but initially only for Windows. Has anyone already created a Delphi interface for video encoding using the built in Windows dlls? I don't have much experience with calling dlls from Delphi. How much work would it be to create an interface myself?

Comment: [Tutorial: Encoding an MP4 file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/tutorial--encoding-an-mp4-file-) seems to have most of the beef and "just" needs to get translated. [MfPack](https://github.com/FactoryXCode/MfPack) seems up to date for wrapping all the DLLs.

Comment: @AmigoJack I wish I could upvote your comment more than once.. thanks!

Comment: @AmigoJack Thanks. I'll think about the effort it would take to translate. I'm surprised it's not been done before. What would be great is a component for FMX that encodes h.264 using whichever platform it's built for. I know that the other platforms also have built in encoders. It seems silly to bundle FFmpeg to duplicate something that's already available on the platforms.

Comment: Maybe this: https://github.com/Ghordian/mfpack-media-foundation would be a good starting point?

Comment: @fpiette That looks promising. I've built and installed the package. However, without an example it's difficult to know how to use it.

Comment: Read Microsoft documentation and examples. Then look for the involved API functions in Ghordian source code to know how and where he is calling it.

Comment: I've now found a more recent translation with samples.
https://github.com/FactoryXCode/MfPack

Comment: @XylemFlow I've linked to that in my first comment already.